# Rendering a object onto a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I thought this would be a simple task, but I've been working on this all day but still can't seem to figure it out.

I am receiving a very large (multiple layers of objects) JSON file which I stored in a state of my component, now I need to render that data on the screen. This has become difficult, because within the object I have several others objects which also may contain other objects.

So far, I am using `Object.keys(myJSONObject).map(...)` to try to get it done, however I can't seem to find a way to reach all the 'sub-objects'. Here is my current code:

```
render: function(){
       return (

        <div>

            {
                Object.keys(_this.state.content).map(function (key) {
                     if (typeof _this.state.content[key] instanceof Object){
                  //go through all objects and sub-objects???

                        }
                    return <div > Key: {
                        key
                    }, Value: {
                                _this.state.content[key]

                    } </div>;
                })
            }


        </div>
    );
   }
```

Edit: I should probably add that my object is `_this.state.content`

Edit 2: Here is an example of the object I am looking to iterate through. Keep in mind that is it a lot bigger than this.

```
{ "3.8": [ "Something something" ], 
 "3.2": [ { "Blabla": [ "More things I am saying", "Blablablabal", "Whatever" ] } ],
 "2.9": [ { "Foo": [ "bar", "something something something something", "blablablabalbalbal" ] } ]}
```

Edit 3: Here is how I would somewhat like it to look when rendered:

```
3.8:
 - Something something
3.2:
 - Blabla:
     - More things I am saying
     - Blablablabal
     - Whatever
2.9:
 -Foo:
     -bar
   ...
```

Comment: map iterates 1 level by default, you need to make a recursive function if you want to dig into the sub levels.

Comment: is there an example of how to do that somewhere?

Comment: You should show the object you are trying to iterate through, even if it's just an example. Even better if you have a fiddle with the component and state object in it or something!

Comment: By JSON object you mean JavaScript object, right? [There is no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) . *"I can't seem to find a way to reach all the 'sub-objects'."* You may need recursion. See [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196)

Comment: @ajmajmajma I added an example of what it somewhat looks like in an edit.

Comment: @FelixKling yes, that is exactly what I meant! (what I meant by JSON object was that it was an object made from the JSON data. Sorry about that...) 
Thanks for the link I will take a look over it right now.

Comment: And what is the intended result? Your strings are all in arrays, is the value suppose to be all of the strings or just one? Can you show what the rendered results should look like?

Comment: @ajmajmajma I want to print pretty much all of the contents in there (all of the strings, including the keys). I would like them all to rendered in a tree-like structure, were the outer nodes are parents of the inner ones, if that makes sense.

Comment: @ajmajmajma I will add that to the edit because I don't think I expressed myself appropriately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what your are after: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/PGjVxW

The solution relies on using React's reusable components. It accepts objects of varying levels of nesting as per your example. You can adjust it further to accommodate even more types of objects.

```
const stateObject = {
  "3.8": [ "Something something" ], 
  "3.2": [ { "Blabla": [ "More things I am saying", "Blablablabal", "Whatever" ] } ],
  "2.9": [ { "Foo": [ "bar", "something something something something", "blablablabalbalbal" ] } ]
} 


class App extends React.Component {
  render() { 
    const renderMainKeys = Object.keys(stateObject)
      .map(mainKey => <MainKey mainKey={mainKey} 
                      innerObject={stateObject[mainKey]} />);   

    return (
      <div>
        {renderMainKeys}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class MainKey extends React.Component {
  render() {
    if (typeof this.props.innerObject[0] === 'string') {
      return (
        <div>
          <h4>{this.props.mainKey}</h4>
          <ul>
            <li>{this.props.innerObject[0]}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    }

    const innerObjectKey = Object.keys(this.props.innerObject[0])[0];
    const innerList = this.props.innerObject[0][innerObjectKey];

    return (
      <div key={this.props.mainKey}>
        <h4>{this.props.mainKey}</h4>
        <InnerKey innerObjectKey={innerObjectKey} innerList={innerList}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class InnerKey extends React.Component {  
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        <li>{this.props.innerObjectKey}</li>
        <InnerList innerList={this.props.innerList} />
      </ul>
    )
  }
}


class InnerList extends React.Component {   
  render() {
    if (!Array.isArray(this.props.innerList)) {
      return (
        <ul>
          <li>{this.props.innerList}</li>
        </ul>
      );
    }

    const listItems = this.props.innerList.map(function(item, index) {
      return <li key={index}>{item}</li>;
    });

    return (
      <ul>
        {listItems}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: you can achieve this with a lot less code and components wtih a good recursive function

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

I will do some clean up to better improve that, but it definitely solved my problem and possibly many future problems!

Comment: @ajmajmajma I should have probably asked before, where would be a good place for the recursive function?

Comment: @theJuls not sure exactly where to point you, but i crafted one up quickly. I still this this answer is a good one though! But anyways, something like this - https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/58258/ .

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code which I wrote sometime back to handle 3 layers of nesting in my json file.

**JSON**

```
var a = {
    "parent":{
       "name":"x",
       "child":{
          "name":"y",
          "subchild":{
                "name":"check"
          }
       }
  }
}
```

**Iterator**

```
  Object.keys(obj).map(function(key,index){
    let section = obj[key]
    //getting subsections for a single section
    let subSections = section["subsections"] // get you nested object here
    Object.keys(subSections).map(function(subSectionId,key){
      //getting a single sub section
        let subSection=subSections[subSectionId]
      //getting instruments for a sub section
      let  nestedSection = subSection["//key"] //get you next nested object here

         Object.keys(instruments).map(function(instrumentId,key){
                    //operation
                 }
             })
         })
    })
  })
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Unfortunately it won't work for me :( As it is now I need to keep it in a way that it will accept any number of layers.